# Must CC BY-SA be included for ideas and code taken from Stack Overflow?

Tags: gpl, license-compatibility, cc-by-sa

I'm still unclear about licensing. If I have a project on Github that's licensed under GPL and found pseudocode on a [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20555779/try-to-check-if-tree-is-maximum-heap), must I now dual license my code on Github and GPL as Creative Commons? The idea conveyed in the pseudocode is good yet simple.

The reason I think this is because Stack Exchange is licensed under [Creative Commons Share Alike](http://stackexchange.com/legal), which is a viral licensing scheme.

Comment: See also on SE Meta: [*Is copy-pasting code from Stack Overflow an infringement to CC BY-SA 3.0 or is it considered fair use?*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/270014/193139)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I copy-paste a snippet from StackOverflow into my GNU-GPL project?](http://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/226/can-i-copy-paste-a-snippet-from-stackoverflow-into-my-gnu-gpl-project)

Comment: @NicolasRaoul Possibly, but most of the answers on that question are unfortunately incorrect.

Comment: @TimMalone: Then please put the full body of your answer over there, thanks! :-)

Comment: @NicolasRaoul Am I allowed to duplicate an answer? Given that we have 3 questions which are very closely related it might be worth opening up a discussion on meta and seeking consensus on what we should do. It might be best for mods to merge.

Comment: In that particular case I am sure copying your answer to there is OK. Indeed a meta or chat discussion might be useful, thanks!

Comment: Duplicates should really be used when the questions are really the same. I see differences, such as the fact that `pseudocode != real_code`. Add to that the fact that the question asks for clarification over if a dual-licensing scheme is needed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is CC BY-SA discouraged for code?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/1717/why-is-cc-by-sa-discouraged-for-code)

Answer (score 4):

I was wondering this same thing not too long ago. I ended up finding that CC-BY-SA 3.0 is [one way compatible with CC-BY-SA 4.0](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239079/317795), which is [one way compatible with GPLv3](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/license-list.en.html#ccbysa).

Therefore, you can relicense what you find at StackExchange under GPLv3. This helps immensely in including SE-found code in a GPL project, because you won't be able to dual-license that project back into CC-BY-SA.

---

**EDIT:** There's one (small) caveat to this: according to the license text, you can't just relicense it willy nilly, you must adapt it first. See [this question](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/1950/what-counts-as-adaptation-for-using-code-licensed-under-cc-by-sa-4-0-in-software) for more information (thanks to [unor](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/users/138/unor) for pointing this out). However, including the source code in a larger project would be classed as adaption, IMO - just don't try to relicense *only* that source code you've found, verbatim, with nothing else along with it.

**EDIT 2:** If the code isn't copyrightable at all - i.e. it's an idea; it's not original enough etc. - then do what you like without restrictions! [This answer on meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/271559/317795) covers the options.

---

It's also worth noting that some people on StackExchange apply non-viral licenses (such as MIT, or even public domain dedication) to their posts in their profiles, which gives you more freedom for their code too (providing it is their original code).

Others may happily give you permission if you ask them. :)

This should still all be done at your own risk though, because you don't actually know for sure where code posted on StackExchange has originally come from.

Comment: According to [this thread](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271080/the-mit-license-clarity-on-using-code-on-stack-overflow-and-stack-exchange) all code posted after Feb 1, 2016 is licensed under the permissive MIT license, so I guess this is a non-issue. Unfortunately the question linked to was made before that. However, can pseudocode be copyrighted? It's my understanding algorithms can't be and pseudocode is a bare representation of the algorithm.

Comment: @inertiablobby That proposal didn't go ahead due to backlash. The licensing link in the footer of every page on the site is still CC-BY-SA 3.0 :) Re psuedocode being copyrightable... I think it still would be, it's basically a program design. Unless of course it's so short that it's simple enough to have no creativity to it.

Comment: You may only license *Adaptations* under CC BY-SA 4.0 (and then again GPLv3). See: [*What counts as adaptation for using code licensed under CC BY-SA 4.0 in software licensed under GPLv3?*](http://opensource.stackexchange.com/q/1950/138)

Comment: Thanks @unor, I've added a clarification to the answer. In the case of this question, including the code in a larger project would class as adaption anyway, but it is important to note the requirement.

Comment: Your answer is correct for code. However, it is wrong for ideas. Ideas cannot be copyrighted. The written code is similar to an expression, and can hence be copyrighted. However, the idea on how to do something cannot - it is not an expression. This is similar to facts - the fact itself is not subject to copyright, but the way it is expressed is copyrightable.

Comment: @Zizouz212 Would you therefore say that psuedo code is not copyrightable?

Comment: @TimMalone I think I would go on to say it is. However, if ideas are being taken from the pseudocode to formulate actual working code, I would consider the resulting code not to be a derivative. However, since pseudocode is really just a bunch of sentences to express procedure, the pseudocode itself is copyrightable. But of course, that depends on our definition of pseudocode - which tends to vary greatly among people.

Comment: @Zizouz212 That feels like a legal minefield to me. I don't think I could sufficiently defend not treating someone's psuedocode as copyrighted (that doesn't mean others couldn't though). But if you read the psuedocode, and go away and write your own function, then yes I'd agree that is not derivative. If you systematically go through it replacing it idea-for-code, maybe it would be.

Comment: @TimMalone Yeah, it's a major battlefield. All the law. The legalese. The insane and deliberately confusing wording. Isn't this all paradise? :P

Comment: Looking at the psuedo-code in question, IMHO that's nowhere near copyrightable.

In order to be copyrightable (Under UK/ european law at least) the work must not be a simple mathematical algorithm, and must have unique properties- Implementing the mathematical algorithm into a wider work would probably be copyrightable, but the algorithm itself isn't necessarily.

I'd probably leave a note in your source as to where this code was found, but it's a long way from ripping of a complete dialog or function.

Comment: @leezer3 I've added a note in the answer about code that might not be copyrightable