# Restrict commercial use to protect users

Tags: license-recommendation, commercial, license, restrictions

I have a piece of software that could potentially be modified to provide revenue, but it is not going to be clear where the revenue goes - I want to add a license condition that ensures all users of any copy (including and modifications or derivatives) of the software know exactly where potential revenue goes.

Background: It is a website that allows to browse existing user content. I don't own the rights to that content. Anyone could host the website (showing the exact same user content as other hosts) and decide to enable/integrate advertisements. I want to ensure that users using any of these hosts at all times know WHERE the revenue from these potential ads go - to the content creator or to the website host.

Implementation of this restriction would be a link to a clear declaration visible on all pages that can display ads and - in case there are ads of both types, for users and for the host - additionally a small text displayed in every ad, e.g. "Revenue goes to user" or "Revenue goes to host".

As for the other terms of the license:

- Keep header in each file linking to original distribution intact
- Source is inherently open since we're talking about a website
- Any derivative work has to include the same condition so that and further derivative is still bound to it

So I'd say MIT would work - if it wasn't for the extra condition.

How would I go about adding such a condition to an existing license without too much trouble?
I don't expect anyone to actually pick this project up and host it, but I want to be sure.

Comment: "Source is inherently open since we're talking about a website" - Just because you can click "View source" in your browser does not mean that the software that serves that web site is open source.

Comment: Your best option is to hire a good lawyer and ask them to write a license agreement for you. Licenses are legal documents, so they are best written by lawyers.

Comment: @Brandin True, but in this case nearly all the logic is within the website itself, and changing that is non-tivial. Although it WOULD be trivial to hide the ad distribution server side so I guess that is valid.

Comment: @Seneral What I mean is that 'open source' refers to a type of license. It doesn't affect the license if the logic is all 'in the website itself' or if you are or are not hiding details on the server.

Comment: @Brandin ah alright, misunderstood. What I was going for with that sentence was: You can always check for yourself in the code to see where the revenue goes - but it's not always trivial when the server sends the adsense id (or smth).
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have [a question](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/q/7365/458) here from someone who is opposed to the current idea of copyright and wanted a license (s)he could combine with ordinary copyright to simulate the effects of his/her view of how copyright should work.  It wasn't really possible to satisfy him/her, because of an underlying problem: **when you take a system designed to achieve certain ends through certain mechanisms, and try to make it achieve similar ends through different mechanisms, it tends not to work well**.

Permissive licences are explicitly designed to allow the monetisation of other people's software.  Copyleft licences avoid the sort of ends you have foreseen, where someone runs a copy of your software to generate revenue which they keep, but the **mechanism** by which it avoids these ends is by preserving the freedom of end-users to make yet another copy which doesn't generate revenue for the offending party.

Many single-use free-with-a-twist licences end up classified as crayon licences; [these are a problem](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/1445/how-can-a-crayon-license-be-a-problem) and may end up making your code unusable.  My advice is to accept the current system's way of achieving the ends you desire: release your code under AGPL and empower users to escape annoying revenue traps.  Alternatively, don't release it at all, thus denying anyone else the right copy it - as Brandin pointed out above, publication doesn't imply licensing.  If neither of those appeals to you, then as Bart has advised, get your new licence professionally written.

Comment: I would not characterize copyleft licenses as "anti monetization", but rather that their goal of end-user freedom renders monetization schemes based on selling copies ineffective (economically non-viable).

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau broadly, I agree with you, and have modified my language slightly to better reflect that.  Thanks!

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Definitely don't want to create a 'crayon' license here. I'll use AGPL as you suggested, makes a lot of sense in this context, and add a comment in the readme regarding my thoughts on ads. Lets me be a bit more freeform as well.