# Does CC BY-NC-SA require me to share PDF of a printed booklet?

Tags: cc-by-nc-sa

I have modified a work, that is a series of paper booklets,  under CC BY-NC-SA, and redistributing those under the same licence.

Does the licence requires to give the PDF (PDF of the printed booklets) if someone asks for it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think it does.

Our [top-rated answer](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/1717/why-is-cc-by-sa-discouraged-for-code/1718#1718) on the problems with using CC licences for software identifies the issue: the CC licences have no concept of source code, that is, the *underlying digital protoform of a work*, which allows generation of new, perfect copies.  In the case of your booklets, that's the PDF form, and the CC licences make no mention of it.

They do specifically cover printed works, see eg [BY-NC-SA 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/legalcode), which says in s1g

> "Work" means the literary and/or artistic work offered under the terms of this License including [...] a book, pamphlet and other writing

So as far as I can determine it is the clear intention of the licence to give end-users the right to copy (non-commercially, and with certain other conditions) the work in the printed form in which it was distributed to them, while making no mention whatsoever of obligate access to any underlying protoform.